# Series expand root of quartic polynomial containing many real parameters and FullSimplify return `Indeterminate`

Tags: simplifying-expressions, series-expansion

Using Mathematica I can get the Eigenvalues of the following matrix (using `Quartics->True`):

```
{{(DE1^2 + EC*DE1 + t1^2)*(1/DE1), ((2*I*DE1*xi + t2*t1)*DE2 + DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), t1^2*(1/DE1), -t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), -J*(1/(2*Exp[I*phi])), 0, 0,  0}, {((-2*I*DE1*xi + t2*t1)*DE2 + DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE2^2 + DE2*EC + t2^2)*(1/DE2), t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), -t2^2*(1/DE2), 0, -J*(1/(2*Exp[I*phi])), 0, 0}, {t1^2*(1/DE1), t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE1^2 + EC*DE1 + t1^2)*(1/DE1), ((2*I*DE1*xi - t2*t1)*DE2 - DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), 0, 0, -J*(1/(2*Exp[I*phi])), 0}, {-t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), -t2^2*(1/DE2), ((-2*I*DE1*xi - t2*t1)*DE2 - DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE2^2 + DE2*EC + t2^2)*(1/DE2), 0, 0, 0, -J*(1/(2*Exp[I*phi]))}, {-(1/2)*(Exp[I*phi]*J), 0, 0, 0, (DE1^2 + EC*DE1 + t1^2)*(1/DE1), ((-2*I*DE1*xi + t2*t1)*DE2 + DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), t1^2*(1/DE1), -t1* t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2))}, {0, -(1/2)*(Exp[I*phi]*J), 0, 0, ((2*I*DE1*xi + t2*t1)*DE2 + DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE2^2 + DE2*EC + t2^2)*(1/DE2), t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), -t2^2*(1/DE2)}, {0, 0, -(1/2)*(Exp[I*phi]*J), 0, t1^2*(1/DE1), t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE1^2 + EC*DE1 + t1^2)*(1/DE1), ((-2*I*DE1*xi - t2*t1)*DE2 - DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2))}, {0, 0, 0, -(1/2)*(Exp[I*phi]*J), -t1*t2*(DE1 + DE2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), -t2^2*(1/ DE2), ((2*I*DE1*xi - t2*t1)*DE2 - DE1*t1*t2)*(1/(2*DE1*DE2)), (DE2^2 + DE2*EC + t2^2)*(1/DE2)}}
```

If I take now the first eigenvalue and want to series expand it in `t1,t2,xi,J` I would normally simply replace all four variables by `#*epsilon` and series expand in `epsilon` (and use `Normal`). However, if I try to `FullSimplify` the resulting expression it returns `Indeterminate` for the second order.

I figured since calculating eigenvalues is not an uncommon task maybe someone has encountered the same issue and found a way to handle these things. For a similar matrix I wanted to do the same and ended up doing lots of `by hand` work. However, I want to study many such matrices so something more automatic or less matrix-specific would be great.

Here are my assumptions on the parameters:

```
Element[EA1 | EA2 | EC | DE1 | DE2 | t1 | t2 | phi | xi | J, Reals] 
&& phi > -Pi/200 && phi < Pi/200
```

**EDIT:** I meant `FullSimplify`, not `Simplify`, I edited the question.

**Edit2:** I forgot to mention that I use the `Quartics->True` option. Here is a MWE with a slightly "faster" matrix, but with the same issues:

```
H = {{EA - c, 0, t1, t2, I*s, 0, 0, 0}, {0, EA - c, t1, -t2, 0, -I*s, 
0, 0}, {t1, t1, EC, 0, 0, 0, 0, I*xi}, {t2, -t2, 0, EC, 0, 
0, -I*xi, 0}, {-I*s, 0, 0, 0, EA + c, 0, t1, t2}, {0, I*s, 0, 0, 
0, EA + c, t1, -t2}, {0, 0, 0, I*xi, t1, t1, EC, 0}, {0, 0, -I*xi,
 0, t2, -t2, 0, EC}} /. {s -> J*Sin[phi]/2, c -> J*Cos[phi]/2}
Assuming[Element[t1 | t2 | EA | EC | xi | J | phi, Reals], 
FullSimplify[#] & /@ 
    CoefficientList[
    Normal@Series[
    Eigenvalues[H, 1, Quartics -> True] /. {t1 -> t*t1, t2 -> t*t2, 
         xi -> xi*t, J -> J*t}, {t, 0, 4}], t]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following update takes into account your edit of the question and your Comments.

Designating the matrix in the Question as `m`, I ran the following:

```
fsteig= Eigenvalues[m, 1];
Normal[Series[fsteig /. {t1 -> a t1, t2 -> a t2, xi -> a xi, J -> a J}, {a, 0, 3}]];
FullSimplify[%, Element[EA1 | EA2 | EC | DE1 | DE2 | t1 | t2 | phi | xi | J, Reals]]
```

Although I received a warning message,

```
Root::sbr: Because of branch cuts, the series may represent a different root of ...
```

I received no error messages.  Concatenating

```
&& phi > -Pi/200 && phi < Pi/200 && EA1 != EA2 && EA1 != EC && EA2 != EC
```

to the second argument of `FullSimplify` (Equivalent to your definition of `FullSimplify2`, which I also tried) does not produce an error message either.  Perhaps, some other part of your notebook has corrupted your results.

**Update**

The addition of `Quartics->True` triggered the error described by the OP, both in his original problem and the faster running one.  I analyzed the latter as follows:

```
scdeig = Eigenvalues[H, 1, Quartics -> True][[1]];
lst = CoefficientList[Normal@Series[
     scdeig /. {t1 -> t*t1, t2 -> t*t2, xi -> xi*t, J -> J*t}, {t, 0, 4}], t];
```

and then applying

```
FullSimplify[#, Element[t1 | t2 | EA | EC | xi | J | phi, Reals]] &
```

To each element of `lst` in turn.  The first element yielded `Piecewise[{{EA, EA < EC}}, EC]`, and the second yielded `0`.  The third, however, yielded two

```
FullSimplify::infd: Expression ... simplified to ComplexInfinity. >>
```

error messages, because it contains denominators that vanish.  One would expect that putting all of lst[[3]] over a common denominator before applying `FullSimplify` would resolve this issue, but it does not.

```
lst3 = Together[lst[[3]]];
```

Then, applying `FullSimplify` to `Numerator[lst3]` yields

```
(* 6*Sqrt[3]*(EA - EC)^7*(J^2 - 4*xi^2 - (J^2 + 4*xi^2)/Sign[EA - EC]) *)
```

whereas applying `FullSimplify` to `Denominator[lst3]` yields `0`.

**Alternative Approach (for "fast" matrix)**

The difficulties encountered above probably are associated with the many branch cuts occurring there.  Instead, expand the `CharacteristicPolynomial` of `H` and its eigenvalues `z`:

```
cl = Simplify[CharacteristicPolynomial[H /. {t1 -> t*t1, t2 -> t*t2, xi -> xi*t, J -> J*t}, z[t]]];
cls = CoefficientList[Simplify[Normal[Series[cl, {t, 0, 6}]]], t];
```

Note that Simplify with no assumptions can be used, because we are dealing only with polynomials.  We now solve `cls == 0` term by term to obtain the expansion of `z`.

```
Solve[cls[[1]] == 0, z[0]]
```

yields `z[0] -> {{z[0] -> EA}, {z[0] -> EC}}`, each with four-fold degeneracy.  Substituting `EA`, for instance, in place of `z[0]`

```
Simplify[cls /. z[0] -> EA]
```

next yields

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 1/16 (EA - EC)^4 (J^2 - 4 z'[0]^2)^2, ...}
```

Hence, we have `{{z'[0] -> J/2}, {z'[0] -> -J/2}}`.  Substituting either of these into `cls` further reduces it

```
Simplify[% /. z'[0] -> J/2]
```

to

```
{0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1/4 (EA - EC)^2 J^2 (2 t1^4 + 2 t2^4 - 2 (t1^2 - t2^2)^2 Cos[2 phi] - 
    4 EA t2^2 z''[0] + 4 EC t2^2z''[0] + EA^2 z''[0]^2 - 2 EA EC z''[0]^2 + 
    EC^2 z''[0]^2 + 4 t1^2 (3 t2^2 + (-EA + EC) z''[0]))}
```

and, finally,

```
Simplify[Solve[%[[7]] == 0, z''[0]]]
```

yields `z''[0]`.  This process can be extended to higher order in a straightforward, although tedious, manner.

Undoubtedly, the same approach can be used for the "slow" matrix.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I used FullSimplify, otherwise the assumptions aren't used. I will edit the question

Comment: `FullSimplify` also produced no error with your assumptions.  However, there are several ways to apply assumptions.  Which are you using?

Comment: `FullSimplify2[x_] := 
 FullSimplify[x, 
  Element[EA1 | EA2 | EC | DE1 | DE2 | t1 | t2 | phi | xi | J, 
    Reals] && phi > -Pi/200 && phi < Pi/200 && EA1 != EA2 && 
   EA1 != EC && EA2 != EC]`, like this

Comment: I also forgot to mention, that I use `Quartics->True`

Comment: Please include in your Question the actual call to `Eigenvalues` that you used.  For completeness, you might move your definition of `FullSimplify2[x_]` there as well and show how you called it.

Comment: I added an example with a "faster" matrix that shows the same errors/problems.

Comment: This is strange because if I do the series expansion "the dirty way", replacing by hand sub-expressions of the first eigenvalue by their series expanded ones (up to 5th order) I obtain third and fourth order terms that improve on my result, that is, if I numerically compare the exact eigenvalues and the series expanded ones and if `xi,J,t1,t2` are indeed "small" then the higher order terms seem to improve my results.

Comment: The `Series` expansion of the `Eigenvalues` of which matrix?  Applying `FullSimplify` to the third term of the fast matrix yields `ComplexInfinity` independent of whether `Quartics` is `True` or `False`.

Comment: Yes I meant the fast matrix. I must admit I am a bit confused right now. I was pretty confident in my hand-made results as they agreed visually with my numerical results. On top of that they agree with what a friend of mine found out with a different method of diagonalising the matrix.